# ¿Cómo descargar vídeos en android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy reproduciendo vídeos en mi app. Estoy buscando información de cómo se descargan archivos y no he conseguido nada...

Con estas líneas de código:

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(path);
 videoView.start();
```

reproduzco un vídeo pasado por url... quiero descargar ese vídeo que se está reproduciendo.

Comment: El código que agregas es exclusivamente para reproducción, puedes salvar el archivo por medio de un FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este método en tu aplicación, el cual recibe el url del video y el nombre del archivo que deseas guardar:

```
 public void descargaArchivo(String myURL, String nombreArchivo) {
        try {
            //path del archivo, almacenamiento extero folder "video".
            String directorio = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "video";
            File miArchivo = new File(directorio);
            miArchivo.mkdir();
            URL u = new URL(myURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(miArchivo,
                    nombreArchivo));
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {                          
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);               
            }       
            f.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

proba esto:

```
File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, option14[i].toString());

       private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
        try {
         URL u = new URL(url);
         URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
         int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

         DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

         byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
         stream.readFully(buffer);
         stream.close();

         DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
          fos.write(buffer);
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
       } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
          return; 
       } catch (IOException e) {
          return; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas reproduciendo vídeos desde tu app debes de crear lo siguiente:

1.- Una carpeta llamada raw que android reconoce como carpeta de multimedia:

2.- Poner un video view en tu app.

3.- La variable "Play" hace referencia a tu elemento VideoView

4.- Y usar la propiedad uri de la siguiente forma

Codigo:

```
path = Uri.parse("android.resource://twinwingscompany.reproducirvideo/" + R.raw.zero);
play.setVideoURI(path);
play.requestFocus();
play.start();
```